# WCF call random failure

Tags: c#, wcf

Could anyone provide me some inputs to identify the issue.

Here is my process:

1. I have an application that does a lengthy image processing, generating multiple multi-page tiff files from single page tiff files, the file separation being the barcode on  scanned single page tiff files.
2. The name of the multi-page tiff file is same as the barcode. These are initially stored in a temp working folder.
3. I go through Each of the multi-page tiff files in the temp working folder path, extract the barcode (filename) and call the wcf service to get the network path.
4. I move the multi-page tiff files to their respective network paths.

My issue is that the call to `GetNetworkPath(imageID)` randomly fails. Here is the service trace. Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

```
at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
at System.Diagnostics.TraceEventCache.get_Callstack()
at System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener.WriteFooter(TraceEventCache eventCache)
at System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener.TraceTransfer(TraceEventCache eventCache, String source, Int32 id, String message, Guid relatedActivityId)
at System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.TraceTransfer(Int32 id, String message, Guid relatedActivityId)
at System.Runtime.Diagnostics.DiagnosticTrace.TraceTransfer(Guid newId)
at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ServiceModelActivity.TransferActivity.CreateActivity(Guid activityId, Boolean addTransfer)
at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ServiceModelActivity.BoundOperationCore(ServiceModelActivity activity, Boolean addTransfer)
at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ServiceModelActivity.BoundOperation(ServiceModelActivity activity, Boolean addTransfer)
at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ServiceModelActivity.CreateBoundedActivity(Boolean suspendCurrent)
at System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ServiceModelActivity.CreateBoundedActivity()
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
at LookupManagerServiceRef.ILookupManagerService.GetNetworkPath(Int32 _imageID)
at LookupManagerServiceRef.LookupManagerServiceClient.GetNetworkPath(Int32 _imageID) in C:\Code\Web References\LookupManagerServiceRef\Reference.cs:line 3250
at Forms.ImageHandler.GetNetworkPath(Int32 _imageID) in C:\Code\ImageHandler.cs:line 452
at Forms.ImageHandler.MoveImages(String _tmpFolderPath) in C:\Code\ImageHandler.cs:line 391
at Forms.ImageHandler.ProcessImages(String _sourceFolder, String _tmpFolder, IList`1 _prcBarcodes) in C:\Code\ImageHandler.cs:line 337
at Forms.ImageHandler.GenerateMultiPageTiffFiles(Int32 _scanBatchID) in C:\Code\ImageHandler.cs:line 58
at Forms.frmProcessScannedImages.btnProcessBatch_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Code\frmProcessScannedImages.cs:line 44
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason,     Int32 pvLoopData)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(ApplicationContext context)
at Program.Main() in C:\Code\Program.cs:line 93
at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean ignoreSyncCtx)`enter code here`
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

I tried checking the service state and opening the service if it faulted but that did not help.

```
LookupManagerServiceClient client = new LookupManagerServiceClient();
    if (client.State.Equals(System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Faulted) ||
        client.State.Equals(System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Closing) ||
        client.State.Equals(System.ServiceModel.CommunicationState.Closed))
    {
             client = new LookupManagerServiceRef.LookupManagerServiceClient();
            }
_result = client.GetNetworkPath(_imageID);
```

Comment: The exception message might be helpful.

Comment: Brian, I think I just solved my issue. Instead of delaying the call to WCF after image processing, making the call to the wcf as soon as I have the imageID helped. I modified my list<string> which was holding the imageIDs into a structure to hold imageID and the network path. Thank You for your time.

Comment: The issue is back at the next service call that I make. The exception message is not related to the service operation at all, all I see is "Invalid token for impersonation - it cannot be duplicated.". I read in one of the posts that if the http session is kept idle for a long time, it will invalidate the underlying tcp connection. In my case the http session was idle for 3-5 minutes, and the service call fails. Is there anything that would help me find the underlying channel of the wcf client to know if it is active or inactive? Thank Yor for your time.